# Accessing raspberry pi remotely without static IP?

Tags: pi-3, ssh, remote, static-ip

I have an pi connected to a machine, i can access the machine from a PC which is connected to the LAN, if i use my static IP i can access the machine from anywhere, but the problem is, An LAN with static IP will not be available everywhere, so is there any way to connect that raspberry pi even if i use a network like mobile hotspot without static IP?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Especially take note that a search of existing questions/answers is adviced to avoid duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry pi team suggests using weaved for accessing your pi remotely.

Check this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/README.md)

You need install waved client in your machine and use weaved account to connect to your pi.

Comment: That IS NOT for access over a LAN.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service like noip.com.

Sign up for an account, install the program on your raspberry pi so that it can track the ip address as it changes. Then when you log in with ssh, use the noip supplied address instead of your ip address.

You may need to forward port 22 to your Raspberry Pi's local ip address on your router too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PiTunnel.com](https://www.pitunnel.com). No static IP required.

Easy to install and you'll get remote access to your Raspberry Pi instantly. Remote Terminal, Status Monitoring and you can create tunnels for things like web server and vnc.

(Full disclosure, I'm the creator of PiTunnel and we created it specifically to solve this problem for ourselves and others looking to do the same thing)

Comment: this was the fastest setup for me to access a rasp pi by ssh used to manage our warehouse printers.

Answer (score -1):

**2nd edit:**

Since I got a lot of downvotes, I want to fix my mistake and suggest humble advice.

If possible, you may want to use the 'arp-scan' command to list IP addresses with associated MAC-Addresses. Since MAC-Address is 'unique,' it should be possible to filter the output. But first, we need to install it:

```
sudo apt install arp-scan
```

For example, in Python:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen('sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 192.168.1.0/24', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in output.stdout:
    print(line.split())
```

the output will be:

```
[b'Interface:', b'wlan0,', b'datalink', b'type:', b'EN10MB', b'(Ethernet)']
[b'Starting', b'arp-scan', b'1.9.5', b'with', b'256', b'hosts', b'(https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)']
[b'192.168.1.1', b'44:fb:5a:a8:90:48', b'(Unknown)']
[b'192.168.1.2', b'a0:1d:48:b1:dd:b2', b'Hewlett', b'Packard']
[b'192.168.1.5', b'90:59:af:7e:68:6e', b'Texas', b'Instruments']
[b'192.168.1.3', b'0c:a8:a7:c9:a1:8a', b'(Unknown)']
[]
[b'4', b'packets', b'received', b'by', b'filter,', b'0', b'packets', b'dropped', b'by', b'kernel']
[b'Ending', b'arp-scan', b'1.9.5:', b'256', b'hosts', b'scanned', b'in', b'4.208', b'seconds', b'(60.84', b'hosts/sec).', b'4', b'responded']
```

You know what to do next. If anyone knows how to do it with awk/sed, please comment. Thanks.

Another alternative is to use network scanner software, such as [Angry IP scanner](https://angryip.org/download/#windows), [NMAP](https://nmap.org/), etc. Both methods should work in a typical situation.

**1st edit:**
To overcome the dynamic address, you may want to use Dynamic DNS. But, you will need a domain for this.
I use Cloudflare to manage my domain names and use this [tutorial](https://letswp.io/cloudflare-as-dynamic-dns-raspberry-pi/) to update domain records periodically to my public address.
There are some alternatives, such as [freedns.afraid.org](https://freedns.afraid.org/) or maybe [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), please suit your need.

And don't forget to forward the port.

**original answer:**

Try port forwarding or DMZ. You will need a router for this.

Comment: You are welcome, I am sorry for short answer.

Comment: not an issue ;)